# How to change ActionBar Colour

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles

I am trying to change my App `ActionBar` colour to no success. I am using the this library https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer;

Here is the style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color_c</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Toolbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">5dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/color_a</item>
        <item name="background">@color/color_a</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyNavigationDrawerTheme" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_a</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_a</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="rippleBackport">true</item>
        <item name="singleAccount">true</item>
        <item name="multipaneSupport">true</item>
        <!--<item name="learningPattern">false</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="MySubheaderTheme">
        <item name="subheaderTitleColor">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MySectionTheme" >
        <item name="sectionColorIcon">#000000</item>
        <item name="sectionColorText">#000000</item>
        <item name="sectionColorNotification">#000000</item>
        <item name="sectionBackgroundColorPressed">#160000FF</item>
        <item name="sectionBackgroundColorSelected">#0A0000FF</item>
        <item name="sectionBackgroundColor">#000000FF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I use the `MyNavigationDrawerTheme` theme for my activities.

Comment: What values of the colors.xml have you tried to change?

Comment: It is Blue and I want to change to Green

Comment: Okay... again, what does `colors.xml`  look like and have you changed `@color/color_a`?

Comment: This is in my colors.xml `<color name="color_a">#25a402</color>`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question with that information as well as your Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the action bar color using the `android:colorPrimary` attribute:

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Based on information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Comment: I have done that but it is still the same. My testing device has API 18

Comment: You might try using one of the `Theme.AppCompat` as the parent and also including the default namespace version of `colorPrimary` in the style instead of `android:colorPrimary`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your styles also for v21 and above with a small change (because they natively support material theme).
And in values-v21/style.xml add `android:colorPrimary` and others attributes with `android:` prefix to your style:

```
<style name="MyNavigationDrawerTheme" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/color_a</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_a</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
        <!--...-->
    </style>
```

Comment: I have done that but it is still the same. My testing device has API 18